# AJAX+PHP Unexpected Illegal Token

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using AJAX to get a response from PHP, it worked everything, now I change from plain echo to JSON echo in following code:

```
echo $_GET["jsoncall"].'({"posts": [';
echo '
{
"canvasUniqueId":"'.$uniqueId.'",
"canvasUserId":"'.$userId.'",
"canvasFile1":"'.$imageFile1.'",
"canvasFile2":"'.$imageFile2.'"
},';
echo ']})';
```

Then I grab this data when AJAX is completed to set text in HTML element, but I got an error, the console says: Unexpected Illegal Token.

I apologize for making a bad question but it seems very hard to fix, I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Do this echo without the NEW LINE after each entry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop trying to write JSON by hand. PHP has built in tools which will properly escape content for you. Build a real data structure, then encode it. It makes it much easier to see what is going on and is less error prone.

```
<?php

$data = Array(
    "posts" => Array(Array(
            "canvasUniqueId" => $uniqueId,
            "canvasUserId" => $userId,
            "canvasFile1" => $imageFile1,
            "canvasFile2" => $imageFile2
        ))
    );

header("Content-Type: application/javascript");

# Defend against Rosetta attack
# http://miki.it/blog/2014/7/8/abusing-jsonp-with-rosetta-flash/
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=f.txt");
header("X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff");
echo "/**/";

# Now output JSONP
echo $_GET["jsoncall"] . "(" . json_encode($data) . ")";
```

Comment: Good script! anyway, I got Illegal Token again, I think it's related to empty new lines, is there a way to remove empty new lines?

Comment: You have some code which outputs something to the body *before* this code runs. Possibly new lines before the `<?php`. You'll need to delete those with your editor.

Comment: There no new lines before <?php now

Comment: Also, the PHP `=>` doesn't work like the Perl fat comma (whoops) so you should quote the key names in PHP. (Fixed that in the answer).

Comment: If you are still getting "cannot modify header information" then you must have something else giving output.

Comment: The last line of your screenshot shows that `$_GET["jsoncall"]` is blank. The problem is with how you are calling the Ajax URL.

Comment: Looking at another part of the screenshot, it looks like you are using XMLHttpRequest to make a POST request instead of script to make a JSONP request. You need to decide what sort of data you actually want.

Comment: Sorry! you're right about $_GET["jsoncall"], now I managed to correct it and it worked like a charm, one optional question, I would like to get ordered lines, is there a way to parse JSON ?

Comment: Objects are unordered. Use an array if order matters.

Comment: I'm curious about Rosetta Flash, why did you add it? My app is not using flash, it's HTML5 canvas. I'm reading it now.

Comment: @Ivan — Unprotected JSONP endpoints allow the attacker to inject Flash onto your site, so you can end up using it without meaning to.